# turning Fire Animation to actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript

**How** can I turn Fire animation from `Timeline` to `ActionScript 3 Code`?

If I use fire animation on timeline for my game, characters position and level details would reset.

Do you have any advice about how can I handle this issue?

My experience on flash is too low, sorry for this kind of question
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Fire movieclip that contains all the fire timepline animation. Then simply call it's **play()** function to play it.